# How should I store a bitmap image in memory for processing?

Tags: python, image-processing, bitmap

I am writing a pure python bitmap decoder/encoder. I am having trouble figuring out the best way to store the pixel data in memory so that I can do some processing on the image. Here is my current code:

```
image.seek(0)
file_type = image.read(2)
print(f"File Type: {file_type.decode('ascii')}")

meta = image.read(12)
file_size, _, _, offset = unpack("<I2HI", meta)
print(f"File Size: {file_size}")
print(f"Header Offset: {offset}")
image_header = image.read(40)

header_size, image_width, image_height, \
color_planes, bits_per_pixel, compression, \
image_size, horizontal_reso, vertical_reso,\
color_palette, important_color = unpack("<3I2h2I4I", image_header)

print(f"Header size: {header_size}")
print(f'Width: {image_width} | Height: {image_height}')
print(f"Bits per pixel: {bits_per_pixel}")
print(f"Image size: {image_size}")
print(f"Horizontal reso: {horizontal_reso} | Vertical reso: {vertical_reso}")
print(f"Color palette: {color_palette}")
raw_image = image.read()

def calculate_row_size(bits_per_pixel, image_width):
    return math.ceil((bits_per_pixel * image_width)/32)*4

def calculate_row_padding(bits_per_pixel, image_width):
    return ((bits_per_pixel//8) * image_width) % 4

def calculate_pixel_array_size(row_size, image_height):
    return row_size * abs(image_height)

def calculate_number_of_rows(row_size, pixel_array_size):
    return pixel_array_size//row_size

row_size = calculate_row_size(bits_per_pixel, image_width)
pixel_array_size = calculate_pixel_array_size(row_size, image_height)
number_of_rows = calculate_number_of_rows(row_size, pixel_array_size)
row_pad = calculate_row_padding(bits_per_pixel, image_width)

print(f"Row size: {row_size}")
print(f"Pixel array size: {pixel_array_size}")
print(f"Number of rows: {number_of_rows}")
print(f"Padding size: {row_pad}")

final_image = b''

def chunk(data, n):
    for i in range(0, len(data), n):
        yield i, data[i:i+n]

for i, data in chunk(raw_image, row_size):
    for i, rgb in chunk(data, 3):
        avg = sum(rgb)//3
        final_image += avg.to_bytes((avg.bit_length() + 7)//8, 'little')
```

At the end, I am trying to convert to grayscale (very inefficiently). My thought was to create a list of lists that would store the pixel data in a NumPy array style. Any input would be beneficial.

Comment: use `numpy`. mighty convenient. you could bother with python's builtin `array` type (and module) but eh. -- image I/O for cheating/checking can be had with OpenCV, PIL/pillow, scikit-image, ... and they all are compatible with numpy

Comment: I know that I can easily do this with numpy. I am just trying to avoid using any libraries.

Comment: it's ok to cheat if you only use it as a container. you could write your own class that keeps it all in a bytearray (python builtin type)